# Proof verification request for proving that the infinite direct sum of groups $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of the group $\prod G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum

The following is taken from Hungerford's undergraduate Abstract Algebra An Introduction text

(1) Let $I$ be the set of positive integers and assume that for each $i\in I, G_i$ is a group.  The infinite direct product of the $G_i$ is denoted $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ and consists of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ with $a_i\in G_i.$  Prove that $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ is a group under the coordinatewise operation
$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots)(b_1,b_2,\ldots)=(a_1b_1,a_2a_2,\ldots)$$

Exercise 1:  With the notation as in (1), let $\sum_{i\in I}G_i$ denote the subset of $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ consisting of all sequences $(c_1,c_2,\ldots)$ such that there are at most a finite number of coordinates with $c_j\neq e_j,$ where $e_j$ is the identity element of $G_j.$  Prove that $\sum_{i\in I}G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $\prod_{i\in I}G_i.$  $\sum_{i\in I}G_i$ is called the infinite direct sum of the $G_i.$

Proof for Exercise 1:

Proof:  We assumed the notation of $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ in (1).  For any $c\in \sum_{i\in I}G_i,$ let $c=(c_i)_{i\in I}=(c_1,c_2,\ldots)$ such that only finitely many of the $c_j\neq e_j$ where $e_j$ is an identity element of each group $G_j$.  For any $a\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i,$ where $a=(a_i)_{i\in I}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots).$ since each $G_i$ is a group, and if $a_i\in G_i,$ ${a_i}^{-1}\in G_i,$ and $a^{-1}=({a_i}^{-1})_{i\in I}=({a_1}^{-1},{a_2}^{-1},\ldots)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i.$   Finally, if $b\in \sum_{i\in I}G_i,$ then $b\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i,$ since $\sum_{i\in I}G_i\subset \prod_{i\in I}G_i.$  After having defined our notations, we proceed with our proof. So suppose for any $a, a^{-1}\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i,$ and any $c\in \sum_{i\in I}G_i,$ then $aca^{-1}=(a_ic_i{a_i}^{-1})_{i\in I}.$ Since only at most finitely many of the $c_j\neq e_j,$ then for the coordinates of each of $a_ic_i{a_i}^{-1}$ in $aca^{-1},$ $a_ic_i{a_i}^{-1}=e_i,$ if $c_i=e_i,$, else $a_ic_i{a_i}^{-1}\in \sum_{i\in I}G_i$. Hence  $a_ic_i{a_i}^{-1}\in a\sum_{i\in I}G_ia^{-1},$ and $\sum_{i\in I}G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $\prod_{i\in I}G_i.$

Can someone check if my proof is correct please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am not sure if I should use proof verification or solution verification. I actually don't know the difference between them. I often see people asking if others on the site can check if their work is correct.

Comment: They are the same. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35664/242) for more.

Comment: @BillDubuque I delete the solution verification tag

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it is an off-topic check-my-proof question.

Comment: @BillDubuque when I originally made my post, Shaun told me that it was too broad.  He suggested that I should separate it into three posts and repost them separately.

Comment: But first and foremost you have to prove that $\sum$ is a subgroup of $\prod$, which you didn't do.

Comment: @orione other than that, does my proof look ok?

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in\prod$, call:
$$J(a):=\{i\in I\mid a_i\ne e_i\}$$
Both subgroup and normality verifications for $\sum$ proceed from noting that: $J(a^{-1})=J(a)$, $J(ab)\subseteq J(a)\cup J(b)$ and $\sum:=\{a\in\prod\mid J(a)\text{ is finite}\}$.